# (Swift) How to present HTML in WebView

Tags: html, css, swift, webview

When I try to load url everything works fine. I also tried to load `normal HTML` and that worked fine too.
But this html I got from API is so weird and without tags. Is it possible to somehow present this in webView? 
This is how my HTML looks like: 
 [image]

Code to load it :

```
var html: String
html = cards[Int(slider.value)-1].content
print(html)
webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: The HTML you're seeing is URL encoded. You need to decode it first. Or, how are you fetching it? Maybe you can tell the API which format you want to receive (e.g. accept text/html instead of text/plain)

Comment: Use [`NSString.removingPercentEncoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1409569-removingpercentencoding) if you don't find a way to receive the data without this encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API is returning the data URL-encoded. So you have two options:

- Preferred: Try fetching the data non URL-encoded. Maybe by passing the accept header "text/html", assuming the API might default to "text/plain". Check the API documentation and your request headers.
- As a fallback: Use [`NSString.removingPercentEncoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1409569-removingpercentencoding).